# Django for loop is not showing my items on webpage

Tags: python, django

I have a table on my webpage that I want to iterate product information into and it worked up until I tried adding a paginator. The server runs fine and the rest of the website is functional.

Here are my files:

shop/products.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>On sale here</h1>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <h4>Categories</h4>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <a href="{% url 'products' %}" class="list-group-item"> All Categories </a>
        {% for c in countcat %} 
            <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item catheight">{{c.name}}     
                    <span class="badge">{{c.num_products}}</span> 
            </a> 
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <h4>Note that all products are second hand, unless otherwise stated.</h4>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'search_result' %}" method="get">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q">
        <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-search h-100" type="submit"></button>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <!-- The header row-->
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Stock</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Buy</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Product row(s) -->
            {% for product in products %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{product.id}}</td>
                <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                {% if product.image %}
                    <td><img src="{{product.image.url}}"></td>
                {% endif %}
                <td>{{product.category}}</td>
                <td>{{product.description}}</td>
                <td>{{product.stock}}</td>
                <td>&euro;{{product.price}}</td>
                {% if product.stock > 0 %}
                <td><a href="{% url 'add_cart' product.id %}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></td>
                {% else %}
                <td><a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign red"></span></a></td>
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <hr>
        <div class="text-center">
            {% for pg in products.paginator.page_range %}
                <a href="?page={{pg}}" class="btn btn-light btn-sm
                    {% if products.number == pg %}
                        active
                    {% endif %}">{{pg}}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

shop/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()  
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product')

    def get_products(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(category=self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_list_by_category',args=[self.id])


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

shop/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list,
            name='products'),
    path('<int:category_id>/', views.product_list,
            name='product_list_by_category'),
]
```

shop/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Category, Product
from django.db.models import Count
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, InvalidPage

def product_list(request, category_id=None):
    category = None
    products = Product.objects.all()
    ccat = Category.objects.annotate(num_products=Count('products'))
    if category_id :
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, id=category_id)
        products = products.filter(category=category)
    paginator = Paginator('products', 3)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
    except:
        page = 1
    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except(EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'products.html',
                    {'products': products,
                    'countcat':ccat})

def signupView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            signup_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            customer_group = Group.objects.get(name= 'Customer')
            customer_group.user_set.add(signup_user)
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form':form})

def signinView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('products')
            else:
                return redirect('signup')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signin.html', {'form':form})

def signoutView(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('signin')
```

I'm sort of a django noob so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string to Paginator here:

```
paginator = Paginator('products', 3)
```

You should pass an object_list:

```
paginator = Paginator(products, 3)
```